# How to convert DataTable[] to DataSet in vb.net or c#

Tags: vb.net

how to convert DataTable Array to DataSet?

```
dim DT_array as Datatable()
dim DS as Dataset
Ds=?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

`DS.Tables.AddRange(DT_array)`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25415666)

Comment: @Fourat ~ The direct and literal answer to OP's question is that such a conversion is impossible. It can't be done, given the API that's exposed to us. There's only one way to add an `Array` of `DataTable`s to a `DataSet`, and two answers for this Q&A have provided that information. My answer helped OP solve his problem, as is evidenced by his acceptance of same. The review is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

There's no actual conversion to be done. The `Tables` collection of the `DataSet` is where the tables are stored. Like so many other collections, it has an `AddRange` method:

```
DS.Tables.AddRange(DT_array)
```